# Azure EventHub Message Ordering

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have an event hub trigger that I've configured to listen to an event hub for message. On the sending side javascript script I'm initializing a client as follows

```
const client = new EventHubProducerClient(hubConnectionString, hubName);
```

and initializing a batch as follows:

```
    const batchOptions = {
        partitionKey: sessionId,
    };

    const batch = await client.createBatch(batchOptions)
```

and submitting the batch using the same options:

```
await client.sendBatch(batch, batchOptions);
```

In my host.json I've conifgured the eventHub maxBatchSize as follows:

```
  "eventHub": {
    "maxBatchSize": 1
  },
```

I'm finding that I can't get the messages in order in the EventHubTrigger implemented in Python. While processing each of the List[func.EventHubEvent] and while logging the partition key as follows:

```
def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
    for event in events:
        logging.info(f"PartitionId: ${event.partition_key}")
```

I always seem to get `PartitionId: $None` which seems to indicate that the partition is not being set and potentially why it is out of order.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm following your scenario and expectations.   Ordering of events is guaranteed within the scope of a partition only.   Can you help me understand if you believe that you're seeing events in the same partition appear out of order?   For the events that you're seeing with no partition key set - are you sure they were not already in the partition prior to your publishing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I wasn't passing the value down to the method so once I fixed that it appeared to be working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).